# Create table in Cassandra. Order by

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am creating a table that have the columns below:

- Mark
- Course Name
- University
- Student_ID
- Price Paid

The table should be sorted by mark.
It should be done in Cassandra and I have to implement the two queries below:

```
select Student_ID, Course_Name from table where mark='A'
```

and

```
select Student_ID, max(Price_Paid) from table group by student_id
```

I have tried defining the table as follows but it does not work for the second query:

```
CREATE TABLE table_students(
  Course Name text,
  Price Paid int, 
  nombre_profesor text, 
  id_estudiante int, 
  Mark text, 
primary key(Mark, Price Paid, Course Name, Student_ID));
```

The first query works but when I try to run the second one a message indicating that Price Paid should not be before Student_ID appears. If I switch the order between both, the table is not properly sorted.

I would really appreciate your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to accomplish it with one table - the data modeling rule for Cassandra says - one query, one table.  So if you want to aggregate by `student_id`, you need to have it as partition key. Create a table with primary key something like this `(student_id, course_name)`.

I recommend to read first chapters of [this free book](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide) (Cassandra. The Definitive Guide, 3rd edition)

P.S. Also, having `Mark` as partition key isn't very good - you have too few possible values for it, so you'll have very limited number of big partitions.  Instead, you can for example, add something to it, for example, year, or something like...